Why optional stopping theorems require continuity conditions of martingales?
If we want to prove some form of optional stopping theorem (with a stopping time $T$) for continuous time martingales $M_t$, a typical strategy is to assume that $\mathbb E[M_{T\wedge n}] = \mathbb E[M_0]$ (version for bounded stopping time) and try to prove that $\mathbb E[M_{T\wedge n}] \to \mathbb E[M_{T}].$ This key step usually do not have anything to do with the continuity of $M_t.$ However, the continuity is used if we want to approximate with a discrete martingale. Every version I see involves assuming $M$ to be continuous or cadlag.
My question is: are there any examples of optional stopping theorem failing solely because $M$ is not continuous or cadlag?
